# How to scan at greater than 8-bit color with Image Capture?

Tags: scanning, macintosh, bit-depth

I have an HP Deskjet 3054. I'm scanning using Apple's Image Capture app, and am trying to set the bit-depth to something higher than the default as all of my images come into Photoshop as 8-bit.

I'd rather not have to pay for Vuescan, if there's a free alternative available.

Comment: It seems all the way back in '99 this was a question https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2028155?start=0&tstart=0. What scanner are you using, I assume it is a scanner? Have you been able to scan with higher bit depth with other software?

Comment: HP Deskjet 3054. It seems VueScan allows scanning at higher bit depths but I would prefer to use free software.

Comment: And you're not using the HP software because...?

Comment: If I go to `File > Import > Images from Device` in Photoshop, it opens Image Capture. Also, there is no option to select bit depth in HP Scan 3 either.

Answer (score 1):

An option to do what you want with Apple's Image Capture does not appear to exist. See [Mac Basics: Using a scanner](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204790).

- If available, you can try software provided by the scanner manufacturer.
- You may be able to use [TWAIN SANE](http://www.ellert.se/twain-sane/) if your scanner is supported.